# Converting multiple files using programs that accepts stdin and output to stdout

Tags: bash, io

I want to convert a list of files in a directory to another directory using some preprocessing programs.

I know I can do this for one file:

```
cat "$INDIR/$file" | ./program > "$OUTDIR/$file"
```

And I know I can do this for multiple files:

```
for file in $(ls -1 $INDIR); do
    cat "$INDIR/$file" | ./program > "$OUTDIR/$file";
done
```

But the problem is, the `./program` requires quite some time to initialize, and I don't want that overhead to be repeated, since there'll be lots of files inside `$INDIR`, and my approach above will always restart the `./program` for each file in the directory. This is slow.

So, my question is: **Is there a way to do my task above without reinitializing the `./program`, in bash?**

(edit after @grawity) Understanding that we can't just feed all files in one go to the stdin of `./program` to be able to separate the output, I'm expecting to be able to have a function `create_into_pipeline` that does something like this:

```
process_pipeline = create_into_pipeline(./program.pl | ./program.py | ./program.bash | ./program);
for file in $(ls -1 $INDIR); do
    process_pipeline < cat "$INDIR/$file" > "$OUTDIR/$file.new";
done
```

If it's not possible, then I guess I'll go with creating Python script that will act as a webserver and calling `./program` as appropriate. But I want to know whether I can do this in bash, since I believe it will be more time-efficient in bash than in Python (you can also prove this point wrong and I will go ahead with Python).

---

*Some more details*

The `./program` is actually a sequence of programs piped to each other, as such:

```
./program.pl | ./program.py | ./program.bash | ./program
```

I've considered each program to use the option to process one directory of files and output to another directory, preserving file names. But since I have four programs there, I don't want to create three temporary directories, since accessing harddisk will be slow. So, I don't want this:

```
./program.pl $INDIR $OUTDIR;
./program.py $INDIR $OUTDIR;
./program.bash $INDIR $OUTDIR;
./program $INDIR $OUTDIR;
```

Just an additional information in case it might change the answer (and actually the last program `./program` doesn't have such option to process a directory, so I can't go with this approach anyway).

Comment: Surely you mean `for file in $INDIR/*; do`?

Comment: There are too many files inside `$INDIR`, so I can't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible – at least not without some rewriting of the programs themeslves.

Currently, each of your programs expects exactly one file in its stdin. Some or other part of their initialization is setting up state pertaining to the processing of that single file. They perform this initialization, then keep reading from stdin until they hit "end of file", then exit.

There are two problems here. First is that a pipe doesn't have any other boundaries than "end of file" (when the writer closes its end). You would have to devise some sort of special synchronization to determine when a file ends and another file starts. (Perhaps packets consisting of length + data, with empty packet marking the end of a file.) You'd also need a custom version of `cat` that supports this.

The second problem is that some of the the programs, themselves, *do not expect* more than one file in their stdin. Each of them would have to be rewritten to 1) understand the synchronization scheme to correctly separate multiple files on stdin; 2) move the processing into a loop, for each file read; 3) reinitialize some part of their memory before processing each file (this depends a lot on what exactly each program does).

Note: You say that "the last program ./program doesn't have such option to process a directory". I assume that the other programs *do* have such an option. This means that for those programs, #2 and #3 are *already implemented* and can be just hooked to the multi-file stdin code (step #1, which you still need to implement in all programs).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Good points regarding the boundaries that exist in using pipes. And regarding step #2 and #3 for other programs, they still expect a directory name, so they can't be linked without the use of harddisk, which I want to avoid. I've added more details on my expectation on the question itself, hope you can update your answer as necessary.

Comment: @justhalf: The answer remains the same. There is no magic in "creating a pipeline"; it essentially attaches one program's stdout to another's stdin, nothing more. It cannot magically decide which part of a program should be run once and which repeated for every input.